# Custom Tags with opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter

Tags: jaeger, opentracing

I am using opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter in my spring boot project. It create auto spans for all rest call and do tag with standard tags.

How can i add custom tags for rest call?

Comment: Hi Sumit. Did you find a way to get this done?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a tag to Span creating a new custom Span

```
Tracer tracer = GlobalTracer.get();
Tracer.SpanBuilder spanBuilder = tracer.buildSpan("CustomSpan")
    .withTag(Tags.SPAN_KIND.getKey(), Tags.SPAN_KIND_SERVER);

Span span = spanBuilder.start();
Tags.COMPONENT.set(span, "MyComponent");
span.setTag("mytag", "test");
span.finish();
```

or retrieving the current active Span

```
Tracer tracer = GlobalTracer.get();
Span span = tracer.activeSpan();
```